# Single Row Subquery (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT name from SUPPLIER
WHERE code =
(SELECT code FROM STOCK GROUP BY code HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT code)>=3);
```

I am using SQLPLUS. When the query returns a single result I get the answer I am looking for. However, when it returns more than one row I get this error message:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: What do you expect the query to return if the subquery returns more than one row?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two possibilities: one thing is to repair the sub-query so that it would always return only one row, other possibility is to use `IN` or `ANY` :

```
SELECT name from SUPPLIER
WHERE code in (SELECT code FROM STOCK GROUP BY code HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT code)>=3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery for a single row operation, multiple rows are being returned which won't be `true` (i.e `=` can only compare one value).

Using the `group by` keyword, multiple rows are being returned and that's why the error will occur.

The solution is to use `IN`.